# onClick event on ViewHolder does work inside GridView

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-viewholder

My `RecyclerView` has a `CardView` and my `CardView` contains one `GridView` and some other `TextViews`.

```
public MyCardViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    this.view=view;
    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    nickNameTextView =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_nickname_textView);

    ...
}
```

I set a `OnClickListener` on the `ViewHolder` but when I click inside `GridView`, the click event never gets fired. Here is the code for the `OnClickListener`:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
    });
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you remove the " this.view=view;" i'm not finding issue in this code

Comment: "view" represent the whole view holder. As i want to add a onclick event on the whole view holder, I set the listener on the "view".  so I cannot remove it.

Comment: try this gridView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
    });
}

Comment: this is one of the workaround. but do you know why the parent onclick listener not work on its child view group?

Comment: You can take instanceof object like if (view instanceof Textview) for childviews

Answer (score 1):

Following code you can easily proceed your click events with any element :)

```
public class HomeRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {


    private List<String> mItemList;

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    Context context;
    HomeItemViewHolder mHomeItemholder;

    public HomeRecyclerAdapter(List<String> itemList) {
        mItemList = itemList;
    }


    public class HomeItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView mImage;


        public HomeItemViewHolder(View parent) {
            super(parent);

            mImage = (ImageView) parent.findViewById(R.id.Image); 

        }

    }

    public HomeRecyclerAdapter(List<String> itemList, Context context, RecyclerView mRecyclerView) {
        this.mItemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
        this.mRecyclerView = mRecyclerView;


    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();

        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_home, parent, false);


        return new HomeItemViewHolder(view);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        mHomeItemholder = (HomeItemholder) viewHolder;         


        mHomeItemholder.mImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Handle your code
            }
        });

    }       



    public int getBasicItemCount() {
        return mItemList == null ? 0 : mItemList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return getBasicItemCount(); // header

    } 


}
```

Comment: i can work around the issue by setting the click event on both the whole view and its child grid view. but i'm really wondering why the inside view group not respond to its parent's click event.